# converting dates in a csv file. speed up process

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting

So I have a big CSV file (70k lines) with about 60 columns. 
and I have to convert the columns with epoch time in them to their respective day.

I have a Script that works. However, when I use it on the main CSV file it takes... a long time. I haven't actually let it run fully but it processes about 5 lines a second.

```bsh
i=1
for line in $(cat data.csv | cut -d, -f11);
do
    if [[ $line =~ ^[0-9]{2,}$ ]];
    then
        day=$(date -r ${line} | cut -d' ' -f1 )
        sed_comm="$i""s/$line/$day/"
        sed -E -i.bak $sed_comm data.csv
    fi
    i=$(($i+1))
done
```

This works fine for a smaller version of the file but is taking a long time on the main one. So my question is. Is there a way to do this that won't take hours?

I have looked around to see ways of speeding it up but have come up with nothing so far.

I really only know how sed works so that's why I'm doing it this way for the moment. But if someone knows an obvious way to speed it up I'd be grateful thanks.

small file version: https://ufile.io/3qtcv0hz

Note: running on macOS with zsh

Comment: @αғsнιη it just replaces everything in the column with FALSE

Comment: @steeldriver done.

Comment: @steeldriver  the date -r turns epoch to IST with the day (Mon, Tue... etc) as the lead which is what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With GNU awk (`gawk`) **assuming that the file is "simple" CSV without quoted embedded commas within fields**

```
gawk -F, 'BEGIN{OFS=FS} {$11 = strftime("%c",$11)} 1' file.csv
```

will convert the 11th column from epoch seconds to your locale's preferred date and time format (`%c`).

Similarly with Miller (able to handle more complex CSV, including embedded commas):

```
mlr --csv --implicit-csv-header put '$11 = strftime($11,"%c")' file.csv
```

For other available datetime formats, refer to `man strftime`.

Comment: Thanks! the gawk version worked as I needed.